# 3n+1 solution giving wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, collatz

This is my solution to 3n+1 problem which is giving wrong answer. I have struggled on this one quiet a lot many times since the last 5 days. Please help me figure out the problem in my solution. I have used tail recursion and am also storing a map to track the powers of 2 to reach to the answer quicker.
The link to the problem is [Programming Challenges -  The 3n + 1 problem](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110101&format=html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000000
typedef long long int ll;
map<int, int> globalMap;

void process(){
  ll i = 1, key = 1, value = 1;
  while(value < MAX){
    globalMap[value] = key;
    key++; value *= 2;
  }
  return;
}

ll cycleLength(ll n, ll ans){
  if(n == 1) return ans; 
  if(globalMap.find(n) != globalMap.end()) return ans+globalMap[n];
  else{
    if(n%2){
      return cycleLength(3*n+1, ++ans);
    }
    else return cycleLength(n/2, ++ans);
  }
}
int main(){
  ll i, j, temp, max=-1;
  process();
  while(scanf("%lld%lld", &i, &j) != EOF){
    max = -1;
    for(ll a = i; a <= j; ++a){
      temp = cycleLength(a, 0);
      if(max < temp) max = temp;
    }
    printf("%lld %lld %lld\n", i, j, max);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there are a couple of other problems with your code. For example, your use of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) may cause problems if the input is not correct. Another thing that seems weird is why you're using `scanf` and `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: Please specify what is the input, what is the expected output, what is the actual output, and (if still not clear from the previous three) what is wrong with what you get.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line? It might help you find the problem, or at least narrow it down to some specific code. Also, for some sample input, what's the *expected* and *actual* output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The solution is for a online programming judge and scanf and printf are faster than cin and cout, that's the reason i'm using them.

Comment: The method named `process` does little processing but only populates a `map` containing powers of 2… but you can test whether a number is a power of 2 by `((x & (x-1)) == 0)`. Also the names of `key` and `value` are backward.

Comment: Also FYI, the linked page's definition of "cycle length" is incorrect; the only known nonnegative cycle is (4, 2, 1), and proving that no other nonnegative cycle exists is the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `process()` function will populate `globalmap` such that the cycle length of 1 is 1, but your `cyclelength` function returns a cycle length of 0 if passed in `ll = 1` and `ans = 0`.

So, on the following input:

```
1 1

1 2
```

Your program will output:

```
1 1 0
1 2 2
```

This seems like it might be the sticking point with your sol'n.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will not work if i>j.

Try iterating from the minimum of i,j to the maximum of i,j instead.

Note that i and j have to be printed in the original order, so don't just swap i and j if they are in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But no luck yet. I'm still getting 'wrong answer' reply from the online judge.